# Conditionally replace values of one variable with values of another variable

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I am sure this question has been asked stacks of time but I couldn't find a solution.

I'm trying to replace the values of several variables with values that are present in other variables, based on one condition. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
z <- data.frame (ID = c(23,24,25,26,27),
              Q1.1 = c("Yes","No","No","No","Yes"),
              Q1.2 = c("No","Yes","Yes","No","No"),
              Q1.3 = c("No","No","No","Yes","No"),
              Q2.1 = c("7",NA,NA,NA,"4"),
              Q2.2 = c(NA,"6","9",NA,NA),
              Q2.3 = c(NA,NA,NA,"8",NA))
```

What I want to do is to replace the values of the variables Q1.1, Q1.2 and Q1.3 with the values of the variables Q2.1, Q2.2 and Q2.3 respectively only if the value is equal to Yes. The ideal output would be something like this:

```
z <- data.frame (ID = c(23,24,25,26,27),
              Q1.1 = c("7","No","No","No","4"),
              Q1.2 = c("No","6","9","No","No"),
              Q1.3 = c("No","No","No","8","No"))
```

I've tried several things but none of them have worked sofar. Do you have any idea how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! 
Another base R solution could be this:

```
# split into two matrix the columns
z1 <- as.matrix(z[,2:4])
z2 <- as.matrix(z[,5:7])

# create a data.frame with
data.frame(ID = z$ID,                 # the id
           ifelse(z1 == 'Yes',z2,z1)) # the matching criteria matrix
  ID Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3
1 23    7   No   No
2 24   No    6   No
3 25   No    9   No
4 26   No   No    8
5 27    4   No   No
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

in base R you would od:

```
reshape(transform(reshape(z, 2:ncol(z), dir="long", idvar = "ID"), 
         Q1 = ifelse(Q1=='Yes', Q2, Q1), Q2=NULL), dir="wide", idvar = 'ID')

     ID Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3
23.1 23    7   No   No
24.1 24   No    6   No
25.1 25   No    9   No
26.1 26   No   No    8
27.1 27    4   No   No
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
cbind(z['ID'], map2_dfc(z[5:7], z[2:4], coalesce))
```

-output

```
#  ID Q2.1 Q2.2 Q2.3
#1 23    7   No   No
#2 24   No    6   No
#3 25   No    9   No
#4 26   No   No    8
#5 27    4   No   No
```